# Blend 2017 Pen tool location

Tags: wpf, blend, pen

I can't locate the Pen tool in Blend 2017. On Microsoft page the Pen tool shows above the rectangle. But I seen above the rectangle Pencil tool, then Gradient tool, but not Pen tool!

Comment: While I don't have Blend 2017 installed, I have 2015, did you try pressing P ?

Comment: 2 weeks with Blend, and only  now I learned about pressing P. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you press and hold in 2015 you should get a dropdown that allows you to choose between the Pen and Pencil tools. You could also press P which will select the Pen tool

[image: Blend 2015]